# ASP.NET project question I want to fix code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am facing a situation where a particular SQL query is repeating excessively when I fetch data in an ASP.NET application. I have checked the SQL Server Profiler, and it indicates that the same query is being called repeatedly for each data load operation

I am using this code:

```
var finalResult = 
    serviceResult.Items 
                 .GroupBy(x => x.SummaryId)
                 .Select(x => new ResponseFazitSummary
                                  {
                                      TimeStamp = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault(y => y.ActionCode == "0")?.TimeStamp,
                                      Serial = x.FirstOrDefault().Serial,
                                      AdditionalId = x.FirstOrDefault().AdditionalId,
                                      FazitType = x.FirstOrDefault().FazitType,
                                      Status = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault().Status,
                                      PlantUid = x.FirstOrDefault().PlantUid,
                                      LineUid = x.FirstOrDefault().LineUid,
                                      Computer = x.FirstOrDefault().Computer,
                                      Description = x.FirstOrDefault().Description
                                 })
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
                 .ToList(); // Materialize the final result here

var count = finalResult.Count();
```

Comment: _"and it indicates that the same query is being called repeatedly for each data load operation"_ -  you mean the generated SQL is executed several times for single EF query execution?

Comment: Also - welcome to the SO. Please read [ask], and ideally provide a [mre]. Also please specify .NET and EF versions used.